# Alignment of values separated by ;

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, align

I'm trying to align some values in a table separated by `;`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\geometry{
a4paper,
total={140mm,190mm},
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\begin{document} 


\FloatBarrier
\begin{table}[!htb]
\centering

\caption{Credible intervals}
\begin{adjustbox}{max width=\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{lccc}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{l}{Credible Intervals [Lower Limit ; Upper Limit]}  \\

\hline
Parameter & Model 1 & Model 2 & Model 3 \\
\hline
$\beta_0$ &[-1,315 ;-1,037 ]& [-1,275 ; -0,960] & [-1,317 ; -1,025]\\
$\beta_1$ &[-0,240  ; -0,083]& [-0,217 ; -0,084] &[-0,239 ; -0,084]\\
$\beta_2$ & [0,053  ; 0,268 ]& [0,072 ; 0,256]& [0,046 ; 0,256]\\
$\beta_3$ &[-0,016 ; 0,168] & [0,003 ; 0,188 ]& [-0,019 ; 0,160]\\
$\delta_0$ &[-4,031 ; -2,744] & [-3,988 ; -2,350] & [-0,724 ; 0,633]\\
$\delta_1$ & [-0,486 ;0,591]& [-0,526 ; 0,643] & [-0,793 ;  0,311]\\
$\delta_2$ & [0,402 ; 1,744] & [-0,215 ; 1,618]& [-1,701 ; -0,284]\\
$\delta_3$ & [-0,844 ; 0,220] & [-2,114 ; 0,106] & [-0,152 ; 0,967]\\
$\alpha$ &  & [0,005 ; 0,313] & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{table}
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

The output is below, how can I improve the alignment of the values between brackets?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

A couple of tricks will make the table into using `siunitx` without extensive modifications of the input.

Main trick: change the semicolon into the same as `&`; secondary trick: make seven columns instead of four. Only the last row needs special treatment, in order to avoid the semicolons in the middle.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{booktabs,array,siunitx}

\begin{document} 


\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering

\caption{Credible intervals}

% some tricks
\let\semicolon=;
\catcode`;=4

\sisetup{
  table-format=-1.3,
  table-align-text-pre = true,
  table-align-text-post = false,
}

\begin{tabular}{
 l 
 *{3}{
      S[table-space-text-pre={[}]
      @{\semicolon\,}
      S[table-space-text-post={]}]
     }
}
\toprule
\multicolumn{7}{c}{Credible Intervals [Lower Limit\semicolon\,Upper Limit]}  \\
\midrule
Parameter &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 1} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 2} &
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{Model 3} \\
\midrule
$\beta_0$ &[-1,315 ;-1,037 ]& [-1,275 ; -0,960] & [-1,317 ; -1,025]\\
$\beta_1$ &[-0,240  ; -0,083]& [-0,217 ; -0,084] &[-0,239 ; -0,084]\\
$\beta_2$ & [0,053  ; 0,268 ]& [0,072 ; 0,256]& [0,046 ; 0,256]\\
$\beta_3$ &[-0,016 ; 0,168] & [0,003 ; 0,188 ]& [-0,019 ; 0,160]\\
$\delta_0$ &[-4,031 ; -2,744] & [-3,988 ; -2,350] & [-0,724 ; 0,633]\\
$\delta_1$ & [-0,486 ;0,591]& [-0,526 ; 0,643] & [-0,793 ;  0,311]\\
$\delta_2$ & [0,402 ; 1,744] & [-0,215 ; 1,618]& [-1,701 ; -0,284]\\
$\delta_3$ & [-0,844 ; 0,220] & [-2,114 ; 0,106] & [-0,152 ; 0,967]\\
$\alpha$ & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} & [0,005 ; 0,313] & \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you wish to maintain your current input, the following massaging using [`collcell`](//ctan.org/pkg/collcell) will make sure the ranges are all of equal width:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,collcell,siunitx}

\def\splitlbub[#1,#2;#3,#4]\relax{\def\lbi{#1}\def\lbm{#2}\def\ubi{#3}\def\ubm{#4}}
\newcommand{\workcell}[1]{%
  \sbox0{\hbox{#1}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>0pt\relax
    \splitlbub#1\relax
    $[\ifnum\lbi\lbm<0\else\phantom{-}\fi
     \num{\lbi,\lbm};
     \ifnum\ubi\ubm<0\else\phantom{-}\fi
     \num{\ubi,\ubm}]$
  \fi
}
\newcolumntype{W}{ >{\collectcell\workcell}c<{\endcollectcell} }

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Credible intervals}

  \medskip

  \begin{tabular}{ l *{3}{ W } }
    \multicolumn{4}{l}{Credible Intervals [Lower Limit ; Upper Limit]} \\
    \toprule
    Parameter & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 1} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 2} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Model 3} \\
    \midrule
    $\beta_0$  & [-1,315 ; -1,037] & [-1,275 ; -0,960] & [-1,317 ; -1,025] \\
    $\beta_1$  & [-0,240 ; -0,083] & [-0,217 ; -0,084] & [-0,239 ; -0,084] \\
    $\beta_2$  & [ 0,053 ;  0,268] & [ 0,072 ;  0,256] & [ 0,046 ;  0,256] \\
    $\beta_3$  & [-0,016 ;  0,168] & [ 0,003 ;  0,188] & [-0,019 ;  0,160] \\
    $\delta_0$ & [-4,031 ; -2,744] & [-3,988 ; -2,350] & [-0,724 ;  0,633] \\
    $\delta_1$ & [-0,486 ;  0,591] & [-0,526 ;  0,643] & [-0,793 ;  0,311] \\
    $\delta_2$ & [ 0,402 ;  1,744] & [-0,215 ;  1,618] & [-1,701 ; -0,284] \\
    $\delta_3$ & [-0,844 ;  0,220] & [-2,114 ;  0,106] & [-0,152 ;  0,967] \\
    $\alpha$   &                   & [ 0,005 ;  0,313] &                   \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

`\splitlbub` splits the construction `[lbi,lbm;ubi,ubm]` into four components, while `\workcell` uses the four components to decide whether the lower or upper bound is negative/positive and insert a `\phantom` minus where needed.

Based on your regional settings, `\num` can be made to print `,` or `.` as the decimal separator. For example, adding

```
\sisetup{
  output-decimal-marker = {,}
}
```

to your preamble will keep the `,` as the decimal marker.

---

A slightly small code base for `\workcell` can achieve the same output:

```
\usepackage{booktabs,collcell,siunitx,eqparbox}

\def\splitlbub[#1;#2]\relax{\def\lb{#1}\def\ub{#2}}
\newcommand{\workcell}[1]{%
  \sbox0{\hbox{#1}}%
  \ifdim\wd0>0pt\relax
    \splitlbub#1\relax
    $[\eqmakebox[bnd][r]{$\num{\lb}$};\eqmakebox[bnd][r]{$\num{\ub}$}]$
  \fi
}
```

It uses [`eqparbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) and therefore requires at least two compiles with every change of the content in the table.